# Unable to delete a Data Source in AWS ML

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-machine-learning

I've created a Data source in AWS ML. And I was trying to delete the same using the below program.

```
var params = {
    DataSourceId: 'HelloS3DataSourceNew' /* required */
};
machinelearning.deleteDataSource(params, function (err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
    else console.log("Deleted "+(data.DataSourceId));        
});
```

when I run this the output `Deleted HelloS3DataSourceNew`. But when I went to my  AWS ML console and typed in the ID I get the below Image.

[image]

How do I remove it entirely and create another model with same ID?

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like it was deleted, but is still hanging around for a bit because back end systems take a while to clean up.  Is that the case?  Did it eventually go away?